# Permission denied for .NET core service in Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, systemd

I created a worker service in .net core 6 like example [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-and-systemd/) and deployed it in Centos. its unit is like

```
[Unit]
Description=my test app

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/DaneshAfzar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**systemctl start DaneshAfzar.service** raises an error : **Job for DaneshAfzar.service failed because the control process exited with error code. see "systemctl status DaneshAfzar.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details**

output of **journalctl -xe** :
**Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/DaneshAfzar: Permission Denied**

I used `chmod 777` for the whole directory but error persists.

Comment: Try to start the process from `/usr/local/bin` (copy binaries to there instead of `/usr/bin`).

Comment: @Maroun No change. I still get the error

Comment: what do you mean by *chmod 777 for the whole directory*? Type the exact command you used. Side note: It would be better to do `sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/DaneshAfzar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's asume the service ist called `myservice`. I think it is better to deploy your .net service to the `/opt/myservice` directory or to `/usr/local/myservice` .

Then the structure would look like this:

```sh
# Folder path
/opt/myservice

# path of the executable
/opt/myservice/myservice 
# or 
/opt/myservice/myservice.dll
```

only the file `/opt/myservice/myservice.dll` must be executable

A service file then could be like this:

```sh
[Unit]
Description=IG Render Service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/myservice
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet myservice.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=myservice
# Optionaly define a specific user to run the service
# User=someuser
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

hope this helps.